# Unable to strip img tag from jQuery ajax response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a web app that makes an ajax post to a PHP script, returning a bunch of html.  In the html there is an image and a table of data.  What I am trying to do is separate the image from the rest of the html so I can display it elsewhere.

```
$.ajax({      
  type: "POST",
  url: 'api/service_connector.php',
  data: { selectedmodel: requestdata },
  beforeSend: function() {},
  success: function(returneddata) {                             
  var $response=$(returneddata);
  var test = $response.filter('.testimage').html();      
  alert(test);  
  }                     
});
```

If in my success function I just alert the entire returneddata variable, everything works fine.  So I know that the post itself is working and everything is returned properly; its just a matter of grabbing those image tags that I'm facing.  I have also tried a bunch of other "ways" that I've found on google.  For example,

```
alert($(returneddata).find('.testimage').html());
```

Comment: It would help to see the full contents of `returneddata`

Comment: use json and put in json variable your img tag and in other tag the rest

Answer (score 0):

try [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

```
$.ajax({      
  type: "POST",
  url: 'api/service_connector.php',
  data: { selectedmodel: requestdata },
  beforeSend: function() {},
  success: function(returneddata) {                             
      var $response=$(returneddata);
      var $testimage = $response.find('.testimage');
      $testimage.detach();
      alert($('<p>').append($response).html());  
  }                     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2H2FT/

Answer (score 0):

did you played with jquery's [`$.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) ?

For example:

```
<div class="container">
 <img class="theimage" src=".." />
</div>

...

$(".theimage").prop("src");   // get anything valuable from image first for future use
$(".theimage").remove();      // remove the image from there
```

Answer (score 0):

In php file

add a separator('|') from the first and last of table data

In ajax function

get the content between the '|' symbol.

Same like you can do for image tag also